# Select items and show n article at time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a code like this

```
<div class="container">
  <article class="article1"></article>
  <article class="article2"></article>
  <article class="article3"></article>
  <article class="article4"></article>
  <article class="article5"></article>
  <article class="article6"></article>
</div>
```

I want to show 3 articles at time , and the remaining articles with a button, back and next. How can i do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

We can work on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilsen/mr3vft1a/)

Comment: How about try making progress on your own, when you get stuck.. ask a question.

Comment: Something like this I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/mr3vft1a/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient but works at least.

```
function DisableAll()
{
    // whatever way to make others invisible/disabled
    // and for button hiding/showing
 }


function ShowOnlyN(n,start)
{
         DisableAll();

         for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             $('.article'+((start+i)%6+1).toString()).show();
         }  
}
```